# Horizontal "Lines" affecting image quality

Tags: digital, equipment-damage

This is a picture from my computer camera (0.9 MP) of me covering the camera with a black tissue with not much light in the room. I hope you can appreciate the tiny horizontal "lines". I took a photo while covering the camera in order they are easily seen, but they appear all the time. Also, they aren't static.

I would like to know what phenomenon cause them, if it's posible to solve it and how. Thanks.

[image: "Lines"]

Comment: See... [Why is there a vertical lines pattern in noise?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40700/75526) and [What is noise in a digital photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11910/75526)

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by the camera's [or computer's] auto ISO trying to amplify an almost zero signal to sufficient brightness to become an averagely-bright [mid grey] image. The result is random noise in the resulting signal.

The way to 'fix' it is to hide it by adding more light.

Comment: The lines appear with normal light too. That's my concern. I blocked all the light to show they still show up.

Comment: @MarcoCiafa "normal light" - as in, indoors or "normal light" is in outside in midday...? If the lines appear outside at midday, then you have a problem. If they appear inside, then what Tetsujin wrote still applies...add more light! (What you perceive as "bright" indoors is usually still far too dim for photography)

Comment: Technically, indoors. But I'm next to a window and the sunlight was literally suprailuminating the screen. Both extremes scenarios now that I realise... I will try with different light conditions and places and I will update in the future. Thanks for both answers.